# cannot import name 'Solver' from 'veilcord'

Tags: python, pip

when I run my python code, it gives an error like this, I tried pip install veilcord and it didn't fix it.

```
C:\Users\Yasin Efe Aksoy\OneDrive\Resimler\Masaüstü\Discord-Account-Creator-main>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yasin Efe Aksoy\OneDrive\Resimler\Masaüstü\Discord-Account-Creator-main\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from veilcord    import Solver
ImportError: cannot import name 'Solver' from 'veilcord' (C:\Users\Yasin Efe Aksoy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\veilcord\__init__.py)

C:\Users\Yasin Efe Aksoy\OneDrive\Resimler\Masaüstü\Discord-Account-Creator-main>python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yasin Efe Aksoy\OneDrive\Resimler\Masaüstü\Discord-Account-Creator-main\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from veilcord    import Solver
ImportError: cannot import name 'Solver' from 'veilcord' (C:\Users\Yasin Efe Aksoy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\veilcord\__init__.py)

C:\Users\Yasin Efe Aksoy\OneDrive\Resimler\Masaüstü\Discord-Account-Creator-main>
```

when I run my python code, it gives an error like this

Comment: See https://github.com/imvast/Discord-MassDM/issues/5

Comment: Looks like you need to use an older version of veilcord that has that `Solver` class. The [requirements for one Discord-related repo seem to use `veilcord==0.0.7.4`](https://github.com/imvast/Discord-MassDM/issues/7), but I'm not sure if that will resolve your issue or not. [There are a number of older versions in the cheese shop.](https://pypi.org/project/veilcord/#history)